# Exercise 1.4.1 from Shankar's Quantum Mechanics book

Tags: linear-algebra

**Exercise 1.4.1**: In an n-dimensioanl vector space $V^n$, prove that the set of all vectors $∣Vi\rangle$ , orthogonal to any vector $∣W\rangle \neq 0$, form a subspace $V^{n-1}$ of dimension $n-1$.

I am unable to prove that the dimension of the subspace $V^{n-1}$ is indeed $n-1$, although I can prove that it is less than $n$.

I am trying to prove this with *minimum assumptions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that zeros of a non-trivial linear functional build a hyperplane then you are done by considering $f(v)=\langle w,v\rangle$ (assuming $w\ne 0$).

If you need to do everything from scratch then try to follow the steps (here again $w\ne 0$):

1. Prove by definition that $Z=\{v\colon \langle w,v\rangle=0\}$ is a linear subspace.
2. Prove that for any $v\in V$ there exists a scalar $\alpha$ such that $v-\alpha w\in Z$.
3. Prove that if $\dim Z=k$ and $z_1,\ldots,z_k$ is a basis of $Z$ then every $v\in V$ can be represented as $v=\alpha_1 z_1+\ldots+\alpha_k z_k+\alpha_{k+1}w$.
4. Prove that $z_1,\ldots,z_k,w$ are linearly independent and conclude about $k$.

Comment: Just a follow-up question, given a orthogonal basis for a vector space, and a non-zero vector $V$ how can we construct another basis for this space, such that one of the vectors in the new basis is along $V$?

Comment: @Sidd Well, you can take the new vector and start adding those vectors from the old basis one by one that keep the new (increasing) set of vectors to be linearly independent (the procedure is called completion of a linearly independent set of vectors to a basis). After you finish the completion, you can start with the new vector again and run an orthogonalization procedure (e.g. Gram-Schmidt).